# Is HTML supported in subject line of email

Tags: django, email

I'm sending emails, using Django framework.

And I wonder is it possible to make subject line red, using `<span style="color:red">Some subject line</span>`

Comment: Is this even supported by mail at all? I don't think it's a good idea. Don't do that. Just don't even think about it. Never.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, HTML tags will not be rendered in the `subject` field of an email by [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) compliant clients.

The RFC defines lexical tokens (HTML tags etc.) to be used in the body, not in the header fields. The `subject` is part of the header fields.

Note that this is not a limitation of Django.

If you want fanciness, you might want to look into including unicode characters, which is becoming more and more popular these days.